# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Russian Language Stack Exchange](http://russian.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://russian.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Н > И change in Cyrillic, when and why?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/%d0%9d-%d0%98-change-in-cyrillic-when-and-why)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Nominative possessive vs genitive possessive](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8062/nominative-possessive-vs-genitive-possessive)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I compare two words in the Russian corpus?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8189/how-can-i-compare-two-words-in-the-russian-corpus)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Impersonal Construction: Dative or Accusative?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8202/impersonal-construction-dative-or-accusative)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Emotions/Appearance](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8069/emotions-appearance)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [«Житёнка» — уменьшительное от чего?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8094/%d0%96%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Russian "version" of Elizabeth, Philip, Henry and Paige?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8140/russian-version-of-elizabeth-philip-henry-and-paige)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [“Спелый мой” – what does it mean?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8208/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-what-does-it-mean)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Через Интернет или по Интернету](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8042/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Именование жителей городов](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8192/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---